# MDX: will filter a crossjoin create an arbitrary shape?

Tags: mdx

Will the following filter create an arbitrary shape?

filter(product.product*store.store, my_measure>1.0)

We place it in a subselect, and the MDX is slow, I guess that because the filter create an arbitrary shape, so that the out query can only use cell be cell mode calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried create a set from your filter set and then referencing that?